# Sharing data (not a data set) with a research paper

Tags: publications, data, open-science

How to share data accompanying a research paper? I know there exist some places to share datasets, but sometimes I would like to share data that are not data set (e.g. experiment parameters, results, etc.), and add a pointer in the research paper to the online location of the data. The data size typically range from a few KB to a few MB, and the license is not an issue.

Comment: For those interested in the question on sharing data that *is* a data set, [here](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/59664/how-to-share-a-scientific-dataset-with-the-research-community) is the link.

Answer (score 5):

> e.g. experiment parameters, results, etc.

In the past, I have shared this kind of data from a conference paper in any of a few ways:

- Create an extended tech report version of the conference paper, that includes all that data in appendices. Refer to the tech report in the conference paper.
- Put the data on a lab wiki, and include a link in the conference paper.
- Put the data in a Github repository, and include a link in the conference paper.

I choose between those based on the nature of the data, i.e. which format seems most natural for it.

I've never used [Figshare](https://figshare.com/) for this, but that would be another idea, (if you wanted a DOI for it, for example.) You can put any kind of "research output" there.

Answer (score 3):

The typical way to share a moderate-sized set of data accompanying a research paper is to attach it to a journal article as supplementary information.

For conference papers, however, there is often no option for adding supplementary information.  My recommendation for this case is to simply wait and attach to the extended version that is ultimately published as as the final archival form in a journal.

Comment: Thanks. In my field (natural language processing), conference papers are typically end products: they are rarely transformed into journal papers.