# Where and how are Computer Science researchers publishing datasets?

Tags: publications, computer-science, data

We are publishing articles that use several different datasets acquired from user (clinicians, physicians and radiologists) analysis through interaction to our healthcare systems [1, 2, 3]. We would like to share them so that other researchers can use the same data for post-process analysis and verification.

Our work is a relation between both Human-Computer Interaction (HCI) and Health Informatics (HI) fields by study human behaviour, as a user of an *AI-Assisted* system for [breast cancer diagnosis](https://breastscreening.github.io/). From here, we measure several attributes, with several scales (*e.g.*, [NASA-TLX](https://humansystems.arc.nasa.gov/groups/TLX/), [SUS](https://www.usability.gov/how-to-and-tools/methods/system-usability-scale.html), Time, Number of Clicks, Number of Errors and Qualitative Analysis). It seems to us really interesting to not only publishing around our work but also to provide the information to other researchers.

Our question is as follows:

**What strategies are available to share our dataset?**

In a near future, we would like to take advantage of [Google Dataset Search](https://toolbox.google.com/datasetsearch). However, our idea will be to publish the dataset on [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/MIMBCD-UI) and then publish an [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/) document to link the dataset. By doing this, we will not only promote the dataset for the scientific community but also have the chance of being cited by.

---

<sup>[1] Francisco M. Calisto, Alfredo Ferreira, Jacinto C. Nascimento, and Daniel Gonçalves. 2017. Towards Touch-Based Medical Image Diagnosis Annotation. In Proceedings of the 2017 ACM International Conference on Interactive Surfaces and Spaces (ISS '17). ACM, New York, NY, USA, 390-395. DOI: https://doi.org/10.1145/3132272.3134111</sup>

<sup>[2] Maicas, Gabriel, Gustavo Carneiro, Andrew P. Bradley, Jacinto C. Nascimento, and Ian Reid. "Deep reinforcement learning for active breast lesion detection from dce-mri." In International Conference on Medical Image Computing and Computer-Assisted Intervention, pp. 665-673. Springer, Cham, 2017.</sup>

<sup>[3] Tiago Dias, Helder Araujo, and Pedro Miraldo. 2016. 3D Reconstruction with Low Resolution, Small Baseline and High Radial Distortion Stereo Images. In Proceedings of the 10th International Conference on Distributed Smart Camera (ICDSC '16). ACM, New York, NY, USA, 98-103. DOI: https://doi.org/10.1145/2967413.2967435</sup>

Comment: I edited in the hope of clarifying your question in the main body and to remove subjectivity (by dropping _best_), I hope that's okay. (I also reduced the text size of citations. They could probably be dropped entirely.)

Comment: Thank you @user2768 for your great editing contribution. It is much better now.

Comment: Your question is buried amongst details that are specific to your particular situation, yet those details aren't necessary to answer your question. You could edit further to make the question more predominant. That might help get more answers. (I'm lazy; I'm put off by long questions.)

Comment: But @user2768, the details are giving context around the scientific field of research. Therefore, the question will receive answers regarding generic and specific examples. This is my goal. However, thank you for your opinion.

Comment: The two answers you've been given are completely independent of the specific scientific field of research. I appreciate that you'd like specific answers, but you've gotten no such answers. You might get more answers if you broaden the question. Anyhow, that's just my two cents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Zenodo](https://zenodo.org/) is a EU-funded dataset storage site ran by CERN that seems to be slowly gaining traction. Each dataset gets a DOI immediately when you publish it, so you can refer to the dataset in your manuscript. You can also update your dataset later, which gives a new DOI to the newer version and still keeps the older version there for reference.

A workflow could look something like: (1) Publish dataset in Zenodo, you get DOI for v1. (2) Refer to v1 in your manuscript, submit it. (3) Referee wants to have more stuff in the dataset and you agree. (4) Update your dataset, get a new DOI for v2. Everyone who uses the link to v1 also will be notified that there's a new version available. (5) Submit your edited manuscript, refer to v2 there. (6) Paper gets published, readers see a reference to v2.

Comment: It seems to be a good option for a possible workflow. However, nobody referred the arXiv possibility. What about this option, in your opinion? Thank you for your great answer.

Answer (score 1):

> What strategies are available to share our dataset?

Various options are available, for instance, you could

- make your dataset publicly available on a website (e.g., your personal website); or
- submit your dataset, along with an accompanying manuscript, to a journal that will make it available.

Comment: In your opinion, publishing a technical report on arXiv regarding the dataset is an option? I thought on that, also.

Comment: @FranciscoMariaCalisto Publishing a technical report seems independent to publishing the dataset. But, yes, such a report could be published on arXiv.